# Help me to make 3D effect at AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, 3d, png

I have a graphic sent from somenody, the orginal is a plain AI with 5 layer, but he can export to PNG as 3D graphic (refer to pictures)
I tried use shadow filter at AI, BUT FAILED.
**Can give me some hints/or tell me how to became the 3D effect** .
Thanks
[image: The Final Effect Should Like This]

The Final Effect Should Like This

[image: I make Shadow effect in AI each layer]
I make Shadow effect in AI each layer

[image: But the effect is not 3D as picture 1]
But the effect is not 3D as picture 1

Comment: @Scott - I agree. It looks like a Photoshop bevel and emboss layer effect, possibly a combination of several layer effects.

Comment: Actually.. zoomed in .. it IS merely shadows.. on EACH object. I think I was wrong @BillyKerr

Comment: @Scott - you may be right. Just had a look again, and something similar could be possible in Illustrator, using multiple layers of outset copies of the top layer, with drop shadows applied - like [this example](https://imgur.com/BizLdgi)

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion in the comments, I think something similar could be recreated in Illustrator.

I would duplicate the top shape a few times, apply an outset to layers below to create a sort of stepped effect, change their fill colours, then apply drop shadows. The bottom layer can just be a solid filled version of the graphic.

Here's a rough example of the result, showing the stacked layers. I'm sure you get the general idea.

[image]

Comment: +1 Yup. This is similar to what I concluded after taking a closer look. The teal and green objects are so close in value, they appear to be a "Bevel & Emboss" unless you zoom in and look closer.

Answer (score 0):

The layers are copied and pasted to Photoshop as separate layers. In all layers above the violet layer there's applied Layer > Layer Style > Bevel&Emboss with the same light direction and only the darkening side ON. Here's an example of the effect for the top layer (=separated with the magic wand)

[image]

The violet layer has a drop shadow.

The layers become single if the image is saved as PNG or JPG. PNG should be full RGB, indexed mode like PNG8 damages the shadings substantially.